# How to generate UserLoginType[_token] for login request

Tags: python, python-requests, token

I'm trying to login into a website using a post request like this:

```
import requests

cookies = {
    '_SID': 'c1i73k2mg3sj0ugi5ql16c3sp7',
    'isCookieAllowed': 'true',
}

headers = {
    'Host': 'service.premiumsim.de',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer': 'https://service.premiumsim.de/',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
}

data = [
  ('_SID', 'c1i73k2mg3sj0ugi5ql16c3sp7'),
  ('UserLoginType[alias]', 'username'),
  ('UserLoginType[password]', 'password'),
  ('UserLoginType[logindata]', ''),
  ('UserLoginType[_token]', '1af70f3d0e5b9e6c39e1475b6d84e9d125d076de'),
]

requests.post('https://service.premiumsim.de/public/login_check', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
```

The problem is 'UserLoginType[_token] in params. The above code is working, but I don't have that token and have no clue how to generate it. So when I do my request, I do it without the _token and the request fails.
Google did not found any helpful information about UserLoginType.

Does anyone know how to generate it(e.g. with another request first) to be able to login?

**Edit:**
Thanks to the suggestion of t.m.adam I used bs4 to get the token:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

tokenRequest = requests.get('https://service.premiumsim.de')
html_bytes = tokenRequest.text
soup = bs(html_bytes, 'lxml')
token = soup.find('input', {'id':'UserLoginType__token'})['value']
```

Comment: You can get it with `bs4` or `lxml`